# JSON & Dynamic jQuery Mobile Listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listview

I have a JSON file that contains an array of 3 objects.

When I want to display an object's attribute it display the name of it, for instance if I have an object `car` that has an attribute called `name` and has the value "FIAT" when I write `car.name` it displays " CAR.NAME " on the the listview instead of FIAT.

Here's my code.

---

```
$.getJSON("res/jsonFile/produits.json", function(products) {
    $('#productList').empty();

    $.each(products, function(i, product) {
        $('#productList').append(productLink(product));
    });

    $('#productList').listview('refresh');
});

function productLink(product) {
    var link="<li>" +
        "<img src=product.pic>" +
        "" +
        "<h2>product.name</h2>" +
        "<p>product.desc</p>" +
        "<p>product.price</p>" +
        "</li>";

    return link;
}
```

and here's my JSON file

```
[
    {
    "name": "Coca Cola",
    "desc": "Coca Cola",
    "price": 10,
    "qty": 100,
    "pic": "img/coca cola.jpg"
    },
    {
    "name": "Fanta",
    "desc": "Fanta mini",
    "price": 10,
    "qty": 100,
    "pic": "img/fanta.jpg"
    },
    {
    "name": "Salade niçoise",
    "desc": "Salade",
    "price": 15,
    "qty": 100,
    "pic": "img/nicoise.jpg"
    }
]
```

Comment: javascript is not php, if you print string .. all in quotes will be string .. not a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you're printing the variable names, not their values. Use it like this instead:

```
function productLink(product) {
    var link="<li>" +
        "<img src=" + product.pic + ">" +
        "<h2>" + product.name + "</h2>" +
        "<p>" + product.desc + "</p>" +
        "<p>" + product.price + "</p>" +
        "</li>";

    return link;
}
```